# Solving the non-linear Hamiltonian using Scipy's root finding method

Tags: nonlinear-programming, quantum-mechanics, rootfinding

I am a complete novice to computational physics and am finding difficulty in implementing a code to iteratively solve for a $2\times2$ nonlinear Hamiltonian using Scipy's root solver. I can't seem to find open-source codes that I can take inspiration from and learn by myself. Here is the problem:

Consider a single unit cell consisting of two wavefunctions (corresponding to a dimer). I need to solve for the nonlinear Hamiltonian associated with this by giving initial guesses for my wavefunction ($x$ values).

If anyone here can help me explain, and/or provide me with a link to an example code that solved something similar/using similar methods, I will appreciate it tremendously.

Comment: By the "weak enough" of the non-linearity, you should be able to solve successively $H(\varphi,\Psi_0^{n-1})\Psi_0^n=\bar\omega\Psi_0^n$, $n=1,2,..$ with any $\Psi_0^0$. Then, when that reaches some stability, use the obtained values as initial point for the full non-linear solver. Note that as $\bar \omega$ is also a free variable, you need an extra equation that is given by $\|\Psi_0\|=1$ or a similar normalization.